# Получение Bearer токена для запросов

Tags: python, requests, token

Хочу написать скрипт для отправки запросов на сайт. У меня есть логин и пароль, как я могу получить токен?

Comment: 1. написать функцию login(); 2. использовать куки из браузера после входа на сайт в коде парсера

Comment: Был бы признателен за пример использования куки @Jack_oS

Comment: Разобрался, благодарен

Comment: в браузере F12, вкладка Network, логинитесь, делаете запрос, смотрите что отправляет браузер в Request Headers (кукизы, юзерагент, хост), копируете себе в код, отправляете запросы уже из парсера с этими заголовками...